# Complex analysis question: holomorphic functions on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

A question from an examination on complex analysis:

If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on $\Omega \subset \overline{B(0,1)}$, and if:

1) $\vert f(z) \vert = \vert g(z) \vert$ for $\vert z \vert = 1$

2) If $z_0$ in the open unit disc $B(0,1)$ is a zero of $f$, then $z_0$ is also a zero of $g$ with the same multiplicity.

Then show that, for $z \in \Omega$: $f(z) = \lambda g(z)$ with $\lambda$ a (complex) constant, satisfying $\vert \lambda \vert = 1$.

I don't really see how to do this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are there no conditions on the domain $\Omega$? It doesn't seem true if it is not connected.

Comment: This is not true as stated. Take $f(z) = 1$ and $g(z) = z$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is mis-stated in many ways. Saying a function is holomorphic in $\Omega$ implies that $\Omega$ is an open set. An open subset of the closed unit disk cannot intersect the boundary, so there's no such thing as $f(z)$ for $|z|=1$. After we fix that problem we notice that $f=1$ and $g(z)=z$ is a counterexample.

Correct version of the question: Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the closed unit disk and holomorphic in the open unit disk. Suppose that $|f(z)|=|g(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ have the same zeroes (with multiplicity) in the open disk. Show that $f=\lambda g$ for some $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$.

The hypotheses imply that $f/g$ and $g/f$ are holomorphic. Now the Maximum Modulus Theorem shows that $|f/g|=1$. So any of various results (Open Mapping Theorem, Maximum Modulus Theorem, whatever) imply that $f/g$ is constant.